# Counter is not working in reducer code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am working on a Big hadoop project and there is a small KPI, where I have to write only the top 10 values in reduces output. 
To complete this requirement, I have used a counter and break the loop when counter is equal to 11, but still reducer writes all of the values to HDFS.

This is a pretty simple java code, but I am stuck :(

For testing, I have created one stand alone class (java application) to do this and this is working there; I'm wondering why it is not working in reducer code.

Please some one help me out and suggest if I missing something.

## MAP - REDUCE CODE

```
package comparableTest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable.Comparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class ValueSortExp2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);

        String arguments[] = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Test commond");
        job.setJarByClass(ValueSortExp2.class);

        // Setup MapReduce
        job.setMapperClass(MapTask2.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ReduceTask2.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        // Specify key / value
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setSortComparatorClass(IntComparator2.class);
        // Input
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(arguments[0]));
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        // Output
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(arguments[1]));
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);


        int code = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
        System.exit(code);

    }

    public static class IntComparator2 extends WritableComparator {

        public IntComparator2() {
            super(IntWritable.class);
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {

            Integer v1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(b1, s1, l1).getInt();
            Integer v2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(b2, s2, l2).getInt();

            return v1.compareTo(v2) * (-1);
        }
    }

    public static class MapTask2 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

            public void  map(LongWritable key,Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                String tokens[]= value.toString().split("\\t");

            //    int empId = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0])    ;    
                int count = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2])    ;

                context.write(new IntWritable(count), new Text(value));

            }    

        }


    public static class ReduceTask2 extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        int cnt=0;
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> list, Context context)
                throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {


            for (Text value : list ) {
                cnt ++;

                if (cnt==11)
                {
                    break;    
                }

                context.write(new IntWritable(cnt), value);




            }

        }
}
}
```

## SIMPLE JAVA CODE WOKING FINE

```
package comparableTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;

public class TestData {

    //static int cnt=0;


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("A");
            add("B");
            add("C");
            add("D");
        }};


        reduce(list);


    }

    public static void reduce(Iterable<String> list)
            throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {


        int cnt=0;
        for (String value : list ) {
            cnt ++;

            if (cnt==3)
            {
                break;    
            }

            System.out.println(value);    


        }

    }
}
```

## Sample data --Header is only more info, actual data is from 2nd line

`**ID   NAME             COUNT (need to display top 10 desc)**

1   Toy Story (1995)    2077

10  GoldenEye (1995)    888

100 City Hall (1996)    128

1000    Curdled (1996)  20

1001    Associate, The (L'Associe)(1982)    0

1002    Ed's Next Move (1996)   8

1003    Extreme Measures (1996) 121

1004    Glimmer Man, The (1996) 101

1005    D3: The Mighty Ducks (1996) 142

1006    Chamber, The (1996) 78

1007    Apple Dumpling Gang, The (1975) 232

1008    Davy Crockett, King of the Wild Frontier (1955) 97

1009    Escape to Witch Mountain (1975) 291

101 Bottle Rocket (1996)    253

1010    Love Bug, The (1969)    242

1011    Herbie Rides Again (1974)   135

1012    Old Yeller (1957)   301

1013    Parent Trap, The (1961) 258

1014    Pollyanna (1960)    136

1015    Homeward Bound: The Incredible Journey (1993)   234

1016    Shaggy Dog, The (1959)  156

1017    Swiss Family Robinson (1960)    276

1018    That Darn Cat! (1965)   123

1019    20,000 Leagues Under the Sea (1954) 575

102 Mr. Wrong (1996)    60

1020    Cool Runnings (1993)    392

1021    Angels in the Outfield (1994)   247

1022    Cinderella (1950)   577

1023    Winnie the Pooh and the Blustery Day (1968) 221

1024    Three Caballeros, The (1945)    126

1025    Sword in the Stone, The (1963)  293

1026    So Dear to My Heart (1949)  8

1027    Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves (1991)    344

1028    Mary Poppins (1964) 1011

1029    Dumbo (1941)    568

103 Unforgettable (1996)    33

1030    Pete's Dragon (1977)    323

1031    Bedknobs and Broomsticks (1971) 319`

Comment: Be more precise with *not working on reducer code*: what does happen?

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I got my answer. Please see below, you will get more info on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move `int cnt=0;` inside the reduce method (as the first statement of this method), you will get the first 10 values for each key (I guess this is what you want).

Otherwise, as it is now, your counter will keep increasing and you will skip the 11th value only (regardless of key), continuing with the 12th.

If you want to print only 10 values (regardless of key), you leave the `cnt` initialization where it is, and change your `if` condition to `if (cnt > 10)`...
However, this is not a good practice, so you may need to reconsider your algorithm. (assuming you don't want 10 random values, how do you know which key will be processed first in a distributed environment, when you have more than 1 reducers and a hash partitioner?)

Comment: Really great explanation. I have solved this problem as you mentioned on #3 paragraph `(if condition to if (cnt > 10))`  on yesterday only, but I was confused that why this is not working for `if (cnt == 11)`. But after dip analysis about your's #2 paragraph, I understood it completely.  Thank you.

Comment: But if we are using `if (cnt > 10))` then the reducer will be call after the 11th iteration also (till all key value pair) which is none of use. (Here in my case my requirment is not  #1. In my case I want to print only 10 values (regardless of key)) as #3). Do you have any idea that how I can stop reducer work after 11th iteration. Off course this will improve performance.

Comment: Added sample data in my Q

Comment: @KamleshFandi that is correct. That's why I said that this is not a good practice. Early termination is an issue in MapReduce.